# How to iterate csv file and extract the data as a tuple at a time

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I have a CSV file and I am loading data and I want to iterate the data one at a time randomly to be passed to the agent for moving to the next state so that it represents one state to the reinforcement learning algorithm. The idea is to select the two latencies(latency1 and latency2) and compare it against the required latency if its less a reward of 1 is provided if it's greater than a reward of -1 is provided. The output is that RL will provide the layer which provides the minimum latency, and that point(layer number) will be considered for splitting. for instance RL provides layer3 so it means a DNN model will be split at layer3 into two sub-models.

csv file(25 values)

```
layer  latency1 latency2 
layer1  3.2        1.2
layer2  2.1        0.2
layer3  4.2        2.0 

data_to_load = files.upload()
data=pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(data_to_load['rl_updated.csv']))
data = data.set_index('Layer')
data.head()    
class Environment1: 
   def __init__(self, data):
     self.data = data     
   def step(self, act):
     self.take_action(action)
     reward = self.get_reward()
     ob = self.get_state()
     return ob, reward, done  # obs, reward, done

  def get_state(self):
    """Get the observation.  it is a tuple """
     for index, row in data.iterrows():
          ob=self.data
    return ob
```

Comment: I don't see where you are loading your data.  Also, your code snippet has errors...  action ?= act ?  `done` is not defined.  If you have a csv of data, read in all the tuples into a list, shuffle the list, and put it inside a generator with `yield` to pull observations when needed.

Comment: Hi @AirSquid really thankful for the suggestion. I have updated the code

Comment: Please add sample input at expected output in the question.

Comment: Hi @AshwinGeetD'Sa I have updated the post based on your questions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for the latencies from the rows, shuffled, you could do something like this.  (I don't know why you would use pandas and io):

```
# random sequencer for csv data

import csv
from random import shuffle

filename = 'data.csv'

rows = []
with open(filename, 'r') as src:
    reader = csv.reader(src)
    # read and throw away the header
    headers = next(reader)
    for line in reader:
        rows.append((float(line[1]), float(line[2])))

shuffle(rows)

for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

#### data.csv:

```
layer,latency1,latency2 
layer1,3.2,1.2
layer2,2.1,0.2
layer3,4.2,2.0
```

#### output:

```
(4.2, 2.0)
(2.1, 0.2)
(3.2, 1.2)
```